# Time interval prediction

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models

I want to predict a specific time interval (ex. patient processing time in clinic) with some boolean value like whether this patient has cough or whether he/she has certain disease. I have tried using linear regression but the accuracy, about 0.01, of prediction is poor when using boolean value like 1 or 0 as parameter. Afterwards I add previous time interval as another parameter, the accuracy improved to 0.1 but still quite inaccurate.

I wondered if there are any other linear algorithm which can be used to predict for such question. Or I should used other non-linear one? Or I should see this question as a time serious prediction although it seems that there's no specific relation between the result and the time at given point.

Besides, I also see some posts said that using machine learning such RNN may not get better result while compared with some traditional statistic models.